Apply emphasis fade & focus to select group of series in apache echarts line chart?
I can't figure out how you would default chart options to group series and allow emphasis on a whole group when one of the series within the group is hovered over. For example, if you have four lines:
option = {
  dataset: {
    dimensions: ['weekday', 'l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l4'],
    source: [
      ['Mon', 250, 120, 75, 30],
      ['Tue', 220, 140, 100, 30],
      ['Wed', 230, 160, 80, 60],
      ['Thurs', 260, 200, 90, 20],
      ['Fri', 300, 128, 100, 40],
      ['Sat', 275, 150, 111, 20],
      ['Sun', 250, 175, 89, 20]
    ],
    sourceHeader: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  legend: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: 'line 1',
      encode: {x: 0, y: 1},
      type: 'line',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series',
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'line 2',
      encode: {x: 0, y: 2},
      type: 'line',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'line 3',
      encode: {x: 0, y: 3},
      type: 'line',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'line 4',
      encode: {x: 0, y: 4},
      type: 'line',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      }
    }
  ]
};

Essentially, I want to to group series together like this:
Group 1: line 1 & line 2
Group 2: line 3 & line 4
I then want to control the emphasis of the groups rather than the individual series. So if someone hovered their mouse over line 1, it would keep line 1 and 2 in focus and fade out 3 and 4. Is this possible to do?
I looked at series.id, series.dataGroupId, series.data.groupId, and series.data.childGroupId and I don't think any of those would control the emphasis in the way I am wanting. I also tried series.universalTransition
universalTransition: {
   enabled: true,
   seriesKey: //'group1' or 'group2' depending on the series
}

but after reading about universalTransition, it seems to be about merging data and their associated animations rather than allowing grouping of emphasis animations.
Here's a link to the above code in an ECharts editor.

You can use chart events to change the style of your series on hover. You might also want to look into highlight action but i think animations are not possible in both cases. Also set triggerLineEvent to true if you want the event to not only fire on datapoints. I am currently on my phone and cant try around. best of luck

Thanks, this is what I figured after reading a bit more but the triggerLineEvent is definitely something I would have missed!

Alternative emphasis could be done (as suggested) through mouse events: Example.
option = {
  dataset: {
    dimensions: ['weekday', 'l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l4'],
    source: [
      ['Mon', 250, 120, 75, 30],
      ['Tue', 220, 140, 100, 30],
      ['Wed', 230, 160, 80, 60],
      ['Thurs', 260, 200, 90, 20],
      ['Fri', 300, 128, 100, 40],
      ['Sat', 275, 150, 111, 20],
      ['Sun', 250, 175, 89, 20]
    ],
    sourceHeader: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  legend: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: 'line 1',
      encode: { x: 0, y: 1 },
      type: 'line', lineStyle:{width:3},
      dataGroupId: 1, triggerLineEvent: true,
      //emphasis: { focus: 'series' }
    },
    {
      name: 'line 2',
      encode: { x: 0, y: 2 },
      type: 'line', lineStyle:{width:3},
      dataGroupId: 1, triggerLineEvent: true,
      //emphasis: { focus: 'series' }
    },
    {
      name: 'line 3',
      encode: { x: 0, y: 3 },
      type: 'line', lineStyle:{width:3},
      dataGroupId: 2, triggerLineEvent: true,
      //emphasis: { focus: 'series' }
    },
    {
      name: 'line 4',
      encode: { x: 0, y: 4 },
      type: 'line', lineStyle:{width:3},
      dataGroupId: 2, triggerLineEvent: true,
      //emphasis: { focus: 'series' }
    }
  ]
};
sin = null;
myChart.on('mouseover', (p) => {
  var opts = myChart.getOption();
  if (sin == null) {
    sin = p.seriesIndex;
    grp = opts.series[sin].dataGroupId;
    for (let i = opts.series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (opts.series[i].dataGroupId === grp) {
        opts.series[i].lineStyle = { opacity: 1 };
      } else {
        opts.series[i].lineStyle = { opacity: 0.2 };
        opts.series[i].itemStyle = { opacity: 0.2 };
      }
    }
  }
  myChart.setOption(opts);
});
myChart.on('mouseout', (p) => {
  var opts = myChart.getOption();
  if (sin != null) {
    //reset
    opts.series.forEach((s) => {
      s.lineStyle = { opacity: 1 };
      s.itemStyle = { opacity: 1 };
    });
    sin = null;
  }
  myChart.setOption(opts);
});


If I might make a suggestion - copy and paste your code into your answer so if the link dies one day, it's still around in perpetuity. I have submitted the edit on your behalf :)
